# What is the difference between containers and process VMs (NOT system VMs)?

Tags: containers, virtual-machine, virtualization

As far as I understand, ...

- virtualization, although commonly used to refer to server virtualization, [refers to creating virtual versions of any IT component, such as networking and storage](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/virtualization/what-is-virtualization#types-of-virtualization)
- although containerization is commonly contrasted to virtualization, [it is technically a form of server virtualization that takes place on the OS level](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2226996/software-containers--used-more-frequently-than-most-realize.html)
- although virtual machines (VMs) commonly refer to the output of hardware-level server virtualization (system VMs), [they can also refer to the output of application virtualization (process VMs)](https://www.networxsecurity.org/de/mitgliederbereich/glossary/v/virtual-machine.html), such as JVM

Bearing the above in mind, I am trying to wrap my head around the difference between containers and process VMs (NOT system VMs). In other words, what is the difference between OS-level server virtualization and application virtualization?

Don't both technically refer to one and the same thing: a platform-independent software execution environment that is created using software that abstract the environment’s underlying OS?

Although some say that the isolation achieved by container is a key difference, it is also stated that a system VM ["is limited to the resources and abstractions provided by the virtual machine"](https://www.networxsecurity.org/de/mitgliederbereich/glossary/v/virtual-machine.html)

Answer (score 0):

OS-level virtualization aims to run **unmodified** application for a particular OS. Application can communicate with external world only through OS API, therefore a virtualization component put on that API allows to present different image of external world (e.g. amount of memory, network configuration, process list) to applications running in different virtualization context (container). Generally application runs on "real" CPU (if not already virtualized) and does not need (and sometimes have) to know that environment presented by OS is somehow filtered. It is not platform-independent software execution environment.

On the other hand, application VM aims to run applications that are **prepared specially** for that VM. For example, a Java VM interpretes a bytecode compiled for a "processor" which has little common with a real CPU. There are CPUs which can run some Java byte code natively, but the general concept is to provide a bytecode effective for software interpretation on different "real" OS platforms. For it to work, JVM has to provide some so called native code to interface with OS API calls it is run on. You can run your program on Sparc, ARM, Intel etc. provided that you have OS-specific intepreter application and your bytecode is conformant to specification.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a graphic representation for you, it is easier (for me) to explain the differences like this, I hope it helps.

[image]